# Difference between 料金に付く and 料金に入る

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

> この料金には何が付いていますか

I would translate this as “What's included in this fee?”. 
Given this, could I use 入る instead of 付く in the sentence?

What difference would using 入る or 付く make in this context ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> この料金には何が付いていますか

Without context, it is bit difficult to imagine what this sentence is.

Probably there are various plans gives you something extra in addition to the plan alone. If the phrases are used in that sense, you are asking what extra is in it.

For example, ordering some courses of meal at restaurant, you may be able to add noodles besides basic course of meals when price varies.

So, “What's extra with this fee?” is more appropriate to your sentence.

> この料金には何が入っていますか

I think this sentence is the literal translation of “What's included in this fee?” and it is appropriate to asking for the detail of the fee.